# Determining if a Circle is fully closed in R

Tags: r, image-processing, computer-vision, contour, bioconductor

I am using EBImage.  I need a way to determine if a circle is fully closed or not.  Things I have tried:

1. `EBImage::computeFeatures` eccentricity measure.  This does not work because some circles are almost entirely closed except for a pixel or two.  Also some highly irregularly shaped objects are completely closed.
2. Filling the circles with fillHull and using computefeatures to exclude based on area.  This also does not work because I have small closed circles and larged unclosed circles.

[result of the `ocontour` function showing the points of a closed circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBJWA.png)

[result of the `ocontour` function showing the points of an unclosed circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQKml.png)

I just need a way to reliably classify the two.  Alternatively, if there was a way for fillHull to fill the second image I could work with that.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having similar issues I found a makeshift solution by checking if x == fillHull(x) for each object x.  Not a great solution, but it worked to exclude the objects I needed to.